# OpenCV latent svm model used for cascade classifier

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm new to openCV, and basically i need to implement android app (java) to detect airplanes. Well, I found xml model online, but it turns out that it's latentsvm model, and there is not an implementation of latentsvmdetector in java version of opencv apparently... Is there any chance I can use this model without need to train my own?

Comment: what you had done so far?

Comment: Basically I only need XML model but cascade classifier not latent svm...

Comment: No knowledge of android specific, but I do work on java. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/latent_svm.html. Did you check this link. The code is always there, but JNI bindings might not be present. If not you can check if this has been added in latest version, or file an issue for it. Other option: I know this won't be of much help, but can you get the images used to train the XML. If yes, you can train the cascade classifier model yourself. You should also check con of LatentSVMDetector here  http://answers.opencv.org/question/12124/latentsvm-detector/

Comment: Also check https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/330 . It also has link to bytecode opencv which provides java bindings. Something I probably myself will need in near future.

Comment: You can use c++ code in android and use the Latent SVM in c++.